# Android N: how to dynamically disable multi Window feature

Tags: android, performance, android-7.0-nougat

Is there any way to disable multi window feature dynamically. My application needs to support multi window feature on Tab devices and for handset device it should not support.

If I use android:resizeableActivity flag in application tag its effecting on both tablet and handset devices.

android:resizeableActivity="false"

Answer (score 0):

Create two different [flavors](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html#product-flavors) for handset and tablet. Then you have the possibility to declare different manifests for each flavor and specify:

```
android:resizeableActivity="false"
```

in phone flavor and:

```
android:resizeableActivity="true"
```

in tablet flavor.

Then create two different versions of .apk and pass them to Play Store.

Comment: Is there any other way where keeping only one flavour have true for tablet but false for phones ?

Comment: Refer to [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html)